# What's the difference between IndPetRestriction and Pets PropertyOptionInfo elements?

Tags: sabre

In a `HotelPropertyDescriptionRS`, there are two element related to pets - `<IndPetRestriction>` and `<Pets>`. As far as I can tell, the `<Pets>` element is the standard "pets allowed" one. So what is `IndPetRestriction`?

The reason this comes up is that we're looking at a property (`0042791`) that has:

```
<IndPetRestriction Ind="true" />
<Pets Ind="true" />`
```

and in the HOD text, is shows:

```
<Text>*PET POLICY</Text>
<Text>-25 EUR</Text>
```

However, upon calling the hotel, an agent said that they claimed they do not allow pets. As everyone has experienced, what data they've put in Sabre doesn't always match reality. But I'm still left wondering about `IndPetRestriction`. I could find nothing descriptive about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both elements should match as they are basically the same. If they are wrong it is the hotel's GDS fault, since the information is loaded by them.

FYI
Pets, is the pet policy of the hotel, true means that they accept pets.
IndPetRestriction is meant to indicate if pets allowed in the room, true also means that they accept.

Comment: Ah, okay "Ind" indicates "Indoor" as in in the room. Thanks. And yes, as I mentioned before what's in the GDS is often wrong.